# how to update a composer.json laravel on webserver

Tags: laravel

how to update a composer.json laravel on webserver.I am using laravel.i want to update composer on web server.after copied the files local to server.Please help me.

Comment: Change it and upload it?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have your process a bit "wrong". You never want to update composer or its dependencies on a production server, you want to do that locally. Here is my process, and I hope that it helps you too:

1. Make sure composer.lock and composer.json are not ignored in your GIT or version control. The composer.lock file lists the current versions used in your app
2. Run `composer update` on your local machine. If there are any updates, they will be downloaded and referenced in your composer.lock file
3. Run through and test your app to make sure that everything works as expected.
4. Upload/push your code to your production server
5. Run `composer install` to install the dependencies that you have locally

Again, you do not want to run `composer update` on your production server in case the update in dependencies break your application.

Another alternative to this is including the `vendor` directory in your repo/code base, then uploading everything that you have locally to your production server. This isn't the best solution in my opinion because then you are checking in and/or uploading a lot of files to your server compared to composer handling the process.

Answer (score -1):

you can upload via FTP your updated library in vendor/(your listed library).

hope can help anymore sir :)

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea. Dependencies should always be pulled by running ```composer install``` on production server. Uploading via FTP should be considered only if you don't have an access to SSH.